# MySQL count w/ php trying to optimize for efficiency and non redundancy

Tags: php, mysql, count

My query is working OK. But I am trying to find out the best way to optimize and not have to repeat my $sqlRecCount and $records_count (and would like to know if it's possible to not need to duplicate the GETs). This is what I have now:

```
if ((int)$_GET['products_id'] === 13) {
    $sqlRecCount = "select count(*) as recTotal from table_sql_1";
    $recCnt = $db->Execute($sqlRecCount);
    $records_count = $recCnt->fields['recTotal'];
}
elseif ((int)$_GET['products_id'] === 2) { 
    $sqlRecCount = "select count(*) as recTotal from table_sql_2";
$recCnt = $db->Execute($sqlRecCount);
    $records_count = $recCnt->fields['recTotal'];
} else {
    $records_count = "Updating...";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$id = intval($_GET['products_id']);

if ($id == 13 || $id == 2) {
    $sqlRecCount = "select count(*) as recTotal from table_sql_" . 
                                                       ($id==13?'1':'2');
    $recCnt = $db->Execute($sqlRecCount);
    $records_count = $recCnt->fields['recTotal'];
} else {
    $records_count = "Updating...";
}
```

ps: if you have a set of tables without direct correspondence to the product_id you can rewrite snippet as

```
$id = intval($_GET['products_id']); // casting to int is not required here
$tables = array('13'=>'1', '2'=>'2', and so on);  

if (isset($tables[$id])) {
    $sqlRecCount = "select count(*) as recTotal from table_sql_" . $tables[$id];
    $recCnt = $db->Execute($sqlRecCount);
    $records_count = $recCnt->fields['recTotal'];
} else {
    $records_count = "Updating...";
}
```

ps: **@downvoter** - any comment?

Comment: Your script is slick. I understand how it works, but if I have 10 more tables would I just extend the ($id==13?'1':'2'); like ($id==13?'1':'2':'3':'4':'5'); or would I approach this another way?

Comment: @OldWest `would I approach this another way` record `$x = $id==13?'1':'2'` is the same as `if ($id==13) $x='1'; else $x='2';` As you can see it will not work for 10 tables. Do the tables have any direct correspondence to the products_id? Anyway, check the update.

Comment: I see what you are saying. The count tables have no correspondence to the product ids, if I understand you correctly. Each item I am listing has a specific amount of records that are connected to it. The products_id is not in the sql_table_1, 2.

Comment: Oh yeah! That makes sense. I was thinking on the lines of an array and tried to work it in but could not get it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have a download interface for specific tables. Those tables are zipped in sql format. I only needed to display the actual count of the records next to the download file even though the zipped sql has no key with any other tables.

Answer (score 0):

**The right way** apparently would be

```
if ($id = (int)$_GET['products_id']) {
    $sql = "SELECT count(*) as total FROM table_sql WHERE products_id=$id";
    $res = $db->Execute($sql);
    $records_count = $res->fields['total'];
}
```

or something similar according to your db API syntax

Comment: The OP pulling data from different tables. This answer assumes - based on the SQL statement - that all the data is (or can be?) combined into a single table.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel  Read the OP's last comment to my answer about the tables. I believe that it was your downvote?

Comment: His comment sounds gibberish to me, sorry.